# Django Tables adding a LinkColumn / NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a model with some fields and I want to add a LinkColumn to a detail page. I have a working version, but I want to move to django-tables2

The problem is that the link column doesnt show any link, just a "-"

The model

```
class Events(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The Table.  Here I tried with  `args=[A('id')]` and `args=[A('pk')]`

```
class EventsTable(tables.Table):

    time = tables.TemplateColumn("{{value|time:'H:i'}}", verbose_name='Time UTC')

    detail_link = tables.LinkColumn('detail', args=[A('id')], verbose_name='Detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Events
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}

        fields = ("date", "time", "detail_link")
```

mi url pattern is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
)
```

and the view

```
def index(request):
    table = EventsTable(Events.objects.all(), order_by=('-date', '-time'))
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": PAGE_LIMIT}).configure(table)
    return render(request, "db_interface/events.html", {"table": table})
```

---

EDIT: 
Changing the detail_link to

```
detail_link = tables.LinkColumn('detail', args=[A('id')], verbose_name='Detail', empty_values=())
```

now I got a NoReverseMatch Exception

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(5075,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found
```

the number 5075 is the id of the first event.  I dont know if for any reason is not passing the argument as an int ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
detail_link = tables.LinkColumn('detail', args=[A('id')], verbose_name='Detail', empty_values=())
```

According to the [docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#custom-rendering), `render` methods are only called if the value for a cell is determined to be not an empty value. Since the `Event` model does not have a `detail_link` field, there's no value given to it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and now I got an error. 

`Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(5075,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`



5075 is the id of the firs event.  The error appears at 
`{% for column, cell in row.items %} `

I suppose is a problem with the url but i cant figure it out

Comment: Does it work if you do reverse("detail", args=[event.id]) in the shell or view?

Comment: if I put the url in the browser it works ok, (http://127.0.0.1:8000/db_interface/5075/ , 

but not in the shell.       

Before using django-tables, i used the template code `<a href="{% url 'db_interface:detail' event.id %}">`  which works

Comment: ah, so the url was namespaced. So if you do reverse("db_interface:detail", args=[event.id]), it should work? If it does, replace "detail" in the `LinkColumn` with "db_interface:detail"

Comment: yes, it works , thanks ! 

The only detail is that appears a 'None' string. The link is rendered this way `<a href="/db_interface/5075/">None</a>`.   i'm trying to change the none via attrs but It didnt work.   At the end I need to put an image there, the solution I've found is to create a   `CustomTextLinkColumn`. Do you have another idea?.   Thanks Again

Comment: Finally I just created a TemplateColumn and it works